# How to notify me when someone comment my question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment

I didn't get any notify that someone give comment to me.
How to set the be alarmed?
Thank you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be getting on-site notifications -- in a form of a red dot next to  StackExchange logotype on the top-right. Clicking this and selecting Inbox tab will give you a list of all mentions of you and comments of your posts. (This mechanism does fail sometimes, but this should be quite rare)

AFAIK it is impossible to get some more visible form of notification like e-mail or something.

Comment: It is important to add that you must be logged in to get these notifications.